# Create shadow mask from DEM using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, dem, shadow

How do I create a shadow mask based on a DEM, with the sun conditions (azimuth and altitude) known?

I am using QGIS, and had hoped to use the r.sunmask.position tool for this. The DEM is in UInt16 format as required by this tool, and data has been reprojected to UTM, so all measurements should now be in metres I believe.

However, when I apply the r.sunmask.position command, the output is only seen around the edge of the original raster, rather than within as well. I am sure that the image would contain shadows under the conditions specified, as I am comparing this to a Sentinel-2 image of the same region on which the shadows are clearly visible.

Image attached shows the trial area (actual area needs to be much larger, but is broken up into tiles with different solar conditions), with the DEM shown in black to white (min value =0, max value = 1990). The output of the command is seen as the thin yellow area, mainly in the top left corner.

[image]